# Terminal is not showing what Folder I am in

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I have simple question. Before when I worked in Terminal and I did something like:
change directory to Documents, Terminal would show me what folder I am in. NOW it doesn't. Now it only shows `[User$]` no matter what directory I am in.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
[User$] cd Documents"
[User Documents$]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed your command prompt. Open your `~/.bashrc` file, and at the end add

```
PS1='[\u \W$] '
```

Although you probably want your prompt to be `[user Documents]$`, in which case use

```
PS1='[\u \W]\$ '
```